# jQuery UI autocomplete doesn't work with jQuery 1.6 and jQuery UI 1.8.12. Why? [Edited] now works partially

Tags: php, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to use jquery ui autocomplete but its not working. I just pasted an old code I have, that works in other application that uses with jquery 1.4.4 and jquery ui 1.8.6. Now I'm trying to use with jquery 1.6 and jquery ui 1.8.12. The date picker is working but the autocomplete just blinks the field and shows nothing. Here are the codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>autocomplete</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.ui.all.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#m').autocomplete({
                    source: "search.php",
                    minLength: 2
                });

                $('#dt').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    showWeek: true,
                    firstDay: 1,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });

            });//jQuery End
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="m">uf: </label>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="m" name="m" />
                <input type="text" id="dt" class="dt" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body
</html>

<?php

include_once 'inc/mysqli.php';
//$term = strtolower($_REQUEST['term']); //this was not needed
$term = $_REQUEST['m'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE nome LIKE '%$term%'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$arr = array();
while($obj = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $arr[] = $obj['nome'];
}

//echo '('.json_encode($arr).')'; //for jsonp
echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

I have no patience with this code and probably is because of it that I can't see the mistake.

**[Edited]**
If I make a simple SELECT statement the autocomplete works but not in the way I want. It shows all the results and I want it to show the filtered results by the **$term** variable which doesn't work. It will become very slow when it starts to search the real table with more than 9000 entries.

Comment: The results from the MySQL database are fine. If I run the PHP file with some content for the variable it shows the result correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is search.php in the same folder as this page?

Have you checked the network tab of firebug to see if search.php is being called correctly and returns the correct results?

Comment: I've found the problem but it creates another. If I remove the filter variable, $term, from the SELECT statement the code works, but it doesn't work right because it won't be filtered by the form field

Comment: Can you post some of your php with the select statement in it?

Comment: Can you try this line... $query = "SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE nome LIKE '%".$term."%'";

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've also tried it, didn't work. I'm starting to doubt it works in the way I want.